# Integrating the "flow" note-taking method in math classes

Tags: soft-question, education, learning, lecture-notes

I've recently learned about the "flow notetaking method" found [here](https://www.scotthyoung.com/learnonsteroids/KJdf342RK-09898JKBDSTDFnkquikPP3-Jan/FlowBasedNotetaking.pdf) and [here](https://www.scotthyoung.com/blog/2008/03/06/learn-more-study-less-flow-based-notetaking/), which is supposed to be a good way to learn while taking notes. It was actually created by Scott H. Young, who did the [MIT Challenge](https://www.scotthyoung.com/blog/myprojects/mit-challenge-2/).

I'm trying to figure out how to adapt said method to higher-level math classes, which generally follow the "motivation $\rightarrow$ theorem $\rightarrow$ proof $\rightarrow$ rinse & repeat" general course structure. How would you implement this method?

Alternatively, are there other notetaking methods you find particularly suitable for proof-based courses?